# restrict access on particular portion of website on mobile data in particular region

Tags: php, geolitecity

I have a php website.I want to restrict users to access rates of my website in a particular city.Like in Jodhpur i want to hide my website rates and rest of the cities it is visible.I am facing an issue like when a user is connected through wifi rates are not accessible but whenever connected through mobile data rates are visible even in jodhpur.How to do it

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;
$databaseFile = 'GeoLite2-City.mmdb';
function isVisitorFromJodhpur($ip, $databaseFile)
{
    try {
        $reader = new Reader($databaseFile);
        $record = $reader->city($ip);
        if (
            $record->city->name === 'Jodhpur' 
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
<?php 
                                                                    
$visitorIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (isVisitorFromJodhpur($visitorIp, $databaseFile)) {
    
    $msg= "Sorry, access to this section is blocked for visitors from Jodhpur, Rajasthan, India."
?>
<h4></h4>
<?php } else {?>
<h4><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<?php echo number_format($price1) ?></h4>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Anything not working with the given code? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried the above code.it is working fine on wifi but not on mobile data

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is there even any such thing as city related IP addresses for mobile phones?

Comment: You can't use an IP address to reliably determine someone's location. Complex networks, NAT, VPNs, data center exit points etc...all of these obfuscate the a) the original device and b) its physical location compared to the public IP. It seems you didn't do much research into how IP addresses work, otherwise you might have realised this before now. You would need to rely on the location services in the user's browser or mobile app on the client side, so it can send you an (approximate) location from that - if the user consents, of course. Failing that, ask the user to _tell_ you their location

Comment: can I get the proper solution

Comment: Read the last part of my comment again, where I outlined a more feasible approach.